# Правильная постановка тире.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Из них всего двое в камуфляже - к гадалке
не ходи, десантура!

Тире корректно? Или ставится перед словом "десантура"? Или возможны оба варианта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нет обращения. "Десантура" - не обращение.
Из них всего двое в камуфляже, к гадалке не ходи - десантура!

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: Из них всего двое в камуфляже - к гадалке не ходи, десантура!

Присоединительный оборот, включающий обращение, обособляется с помощью тире.